# How to find the first occurrence of any string given a particular group of strings?

Tags: c++, string

For example, I have 3 strings I am interested in finding in a much larger string. How would I use std algorithms to find the first occurrence of anyone of these strings?

```
std::string str = ...//Some large string to search in.
std::array<std::string, 3> tokens{ "abc", "qwe", "zxc" };

...//Find the the next occurrence of either "abc", "qwe", "zxc" in str, whichever comes first.
...// Process based on the result.
```

Comment: Note: you should improve your question by explaining what you tried so far.

Comment: Check what's available from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_first_of) please.

Comment: Unless you do some initial step to transform the tokens into e.g. a regular expression you then compile, the easiest way is just `std::string::size_type best_pos = npos, pos; for (auto& s : tokens) if ((pos = str.find(s)) != npos) && (best_pos == npos || pos < best_pos)) best_pos = pos;` (expanding `npos` to `std::string::npos` or using it).  Are you looking for something different, or just weren't sure how to code that up?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ re your link above - iterators through `str` will refer to successive characters - how would you orchestrate a sub-*string* search?

Comment: @TonyD It just seemed like a simple thing that would have been implemented in the standard library, considering there's an algorithm that does exactly this, but with single characters.

Comment: @TonyD Well, can't the predicates be customized?

Comment: @Ben: fair enough, but I can't think of anything applicable.  Injecting '|' between tokens to create a regexp would be worth profiling if you were doing a lot of these searches with the same set of tokens and cared about performance.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ not easy/clean to do so robustly... the predicate callback gets no indication of the remaining length of the string, and would have to revert to C style presumptions about NUL termination or take the address of the characters with which it's called and compare to some other data it's kept handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are restricted to the Standard Library, or wish for something simple, the simplest alternative would be to search them one at a time and keep the "best" position:

```
size_t bestIndex = 0;
size_t bestPosition = str.size();

for (size_t i = 0, max = tokens.size(); i < max; ++i) {
    size_t const pos = str.find(tokens[i]);
    if (pos >= bestPosition) { continue; }

    bestPosition = pos;
    bestIndex = i
}
```

---

If you have more resources, or wish for more performance, then [Aho-Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) is a good algorithm to search multiple needles in a single pass. It is definitely more complicated though.

Comment: Any reason why there's no std algorithm to do this?

Comment: @Ben: isn't `std::string::find` a `std` algorithm ?

Comment: There's no algorithm to answer my question. std::string::find only works with one string.

Comment: @Ben: Ah, indeed there is not a single method/function addressing your question; which is often the case by the way, as only the most elementary building bricks are provided.

Comment: Surely it would be cleaner to reverse the `if(pos >= bestPosition)` and get rid of the `continue`. Also it would be good to mark the `bestIndex` with `-1` to start with, so you can easily check if you found at least one string.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: it's very much a matter of taste... `-1` is non-sensical for a `size_t` so I prefer not to use it; the `bestPosition` can be used to check whether something was found or not instead. Regarding `continue`, it's also subjective, I prefer to avoid indentation and have "linear" code.